# Return index of an asked-for value of a list using fold in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, fold, higher-order-functions

I wrote a recursive version of index as follows

```
let index list value =
  let rec counter num = function
    | [] -> -1
    | h::t -> 
        if h == value 
          then num 
        else (counter (num + 1)) t
  in counter 0 list;;
```

It works, but then our professor said we should use a tail recursive version in order to not timeout on the server, so I wrote a new index function using fold, but I can't seem to figure out why if it doesn't find the element, it returns a number greater than the length of the list, even though I want it to return -1.

```
let index2 list value = fold (fun i v -> 
  if i > (length list) then -1
  else if v == value then i                          
  else i+1) 0 list;;
```

Here's my fold version as well:

```
let rec fold f a l = match l with
    [] -> a
  | (h::t) -> fold f (f a h) t;;
```

Comment: `==` is physical equality (which is fine for integers), but you probably had intended `=`.

Comment: Your implementation of `index` is tail-recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Why do you redefine `fold` instead of using `List.fold_left`?

Your first version of index is already tail recursive, but you can improve its style by:

- using `option` type instead of returning -1 if not found;
- directly call index recursively instead of a count function;
- use `=` (structural) comparator instead of `==` (physical);
- use a guard in your pattern matching instead of an `if` statement.

So

```
let index list value =
  let rec index' list value i = match list with
    | [] -> None
    | h :: _ when h = value -> Some i
    | _ :: t -> index' t value (succ i)
  in index' list value 0
```

And as already said, `index2` does not work because you'll never reach an element whose index is greater than the length of the list, so you just have to replace `i > (length list)` with `i = (length list) - 1` to make it work.

But `index2` is less efficient than `index` because `index` stops as soon as the element is found whereas `index2` always evaluate each element of the list and compare the list length to the counter each time.

Answer (score 2):

Your folded function is called once for each element of the list. So you'll never see a value of `i` that's greater than `(length list - 1)`.

As a side comment, it's quite inefficient (quadratic complexity) to keep calculating the length of the list. It would be better to calculate it once at the beginning.

As another side comment, you almost never want to use the `==` operator. Use the `=` operator instead.